# mysql use the index optimization sorting！

Tags: mysql, sorting, indexing

1. First, I'm creating table `tag`:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE `tag` (
        `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `total_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `idx_sort` (`total`,`total_question`) USING BTREE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=gb2312;
   ```

   > mysql> `explain select * from tag order by total;`

   ```
   +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
   +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   | 1  | SIMPLE      | tag   | index | NULL          | idx_sort | 10      | NULL | 1    | Using index |
   +----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------------+
   ```

   **Sort using index, not using filesort**.
2. When I add column `name` to `tag` table:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE `tag` (
     `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `total_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `name` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `idx_sort` (`total`,`total_question`) USING BTREE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=gb2312;
   ```

   > mysql> `explain select * from tag order by total;`

   ```
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   | 1  | SIMPLE      | tag   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    | Using filesort |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   ```

   **Sort using filesort, not using index**.
3. When I create index only on `total`:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE `tag` (
     `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `total_question` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `name` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `idx_sort` (`total`) USING BTREE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=gb2312;
   ```

   > mysql> `explain select * from tag order by total;`

   ```
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   | 1  | SIMPLE      | tag   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    | Using filesort |
   +----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
   ```

   **Sort using filesort!** Why? I only use the `total` column for sort.

Comment: 因為select `*` - `*` 就是全部，而index裡只含有total的值，Because, you are only index the total column, So, if you are doing `select total from tag order by total` <-- this won't trigger filesort

Comment: I think you can't if you want to have all column return in single query

Comment: What happens if you are not selecting all the columns from the last version table? SELECT id, total, total_question from tag order by total;

Comment: thank！ I know！ you method is right！thank！

Answer (score 0):

you can run `desc select * from tag force index (idx_sort) order by total ;`
you can see the output :

```
mysql> desc select * from tag force index (idx_sort) order by total ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+---     ----+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows |    Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+---  ----+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tag   | index | NULL          | idx_sort | 5       | NULL |    1 |           |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+-------+
```